# Run a wordpress image on Raspberry pi 3B+ lead to permission errors (cannot utime)

Tags: wordpress, docker, raspberry-pi

Hi stackoverflow community, this is my first question and I hope that is placed in the right way. I'm trying to run wordpress with docker on my raspberry pi following this tutorial https://youtu.be/2NO7NS0ci_U?t=660 but I got permission related cannot utime errors (see below).

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Here my setting:

Rpi 3B+ with fresh new 2021-05-07-raspios-buster-armhf-full

Docker version 20.10.8

Commands run in ssh as pi user:

```
curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh
sudo sh get-docker
sudo usermod -aG docker ${USER}
exit
```

After new ssh login (tried also after reboot)

`docker run hello-world` (works fine)

`docker run wordpress` (tried also with sudo: same result)

```
pi@pi3:~ $ docker run wordpress
Unable to find image 'wordpress:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/wordpress
9bd46ffb253d: Pull complete
98086d1d5d87: Pull complete
98c9e09fff15: Pull complete
750c1d85f381: Pull complete
7adaef0b8aed: Pull complete
be28e83c0418: Pull complete
fbd6fa1d3b53: Pull complete
7b21796a11d2: Pull complete
0f297995bbbd: Pull complete
114dd8297762: Pull complete
9e701fe5e40e: Pull complete
0a932f1e11bf: Pull complete
6b11c1479e58: Pull complete
0169ed751f6b: Pull complete
329c18075091: Pull complete
8de87c5a146e: Pull complete
d3d24e76c670: Pull complete
f7b2cd492c04: Pull complete
756a9050c341: Pull complete
9a0598049986: Pull complete
2146293d383d: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:067833b1827e3f035c2c6b4be5336bf5bef498dafeb4f2d18258e439fa90c6f7
Status: Downloaded newer image for wordpress:latest
WordPress not found in /var/www/html - copying now...
tar: ./wp-settings.php: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
tar: ./wp-content/themes/twentytwenty/readme.txt: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
tar: ./wp-content/themes/twentytwenty/comments.php: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
tar: ./wp-content/themes/twentytwenty/functions.php: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
... a lot of rows like those...
tar: ./wp-includes/class-walker-nav-menu.php: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
tar: ./wp-includes: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
tar: ./wp-signup.php: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
tar: ./index.php: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
tar: ./wp-load.php: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
tar: ./wp-config-docker.php: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
tar: .: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

After that long list of tar lines the terminal remains busy (with docker container wordpress active) for about 120sec and then return available, at this point the wordpress container is not running anymore.
I guess that there is some issue with new version of docker or even wordpress (another user recently had the same (unanswered) problem, see comments below video 10 of same tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=emO2PYfrm84&list=PLibQjquhfgjgBEv9GC7X2JWaqSPkD0lAK&index=11&t=2s).

Below the result of "docker image inspect wordpress" command:

```
pi@pi3:~ $ docker image inspect wordpress
[
{
"Id": "sha256:6fdf2c965d1bab7eb9196c29da0cf47339cf48cb204bfeaae2ef2282ab68d0f7",
"RepoTags": [
"wordpress:latest"
],
"RepoDigests": [
"wordpress@sha256:067833b1827e3f035c2c6b4be5336bf5bef498dafeb4f2d18258e439fa90c6f7"
],
"Parent": "",
"Comment": "",
"Created": "2021-09-04T21:40:55.962780748Z",
"Container": "2be306cf6545eda21fece625f49fdcd682a5e7e85cdc086880b97ccb6e72b378",
"ContainerConfig": {
"Hostname": "2be306cf6545",
"Domainname": "",
"User": "",
"AttachStdin": false,
"AttachStdout": false,
"AttachStderr": false,
"ExposedPorts": {
"80/tcp": {}
},
"Tty": false,
"OpenStdin": false,
"StdinOnce": false,
"Env": [
"PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
"PHPIZE_DEPS=autoconf \t\tdpkg-dev \t\tfile \t\tg++ \t\tgcc \t\tlibc-dev \t\tmake \t\tpkg-config \t\tre2c",
"PHP_INI_DIR=/usr/local/etc/php",
"APACHE_CONFDIR=/etc/apache2",
"APACHE_ENVVARS=/etc/apache2/envvars",
"PHP_EXTRA_BUILD_DEPS=apache2-dev",
"PHP_EXTRA_CONFIGURE_ARGS=--with-apxs2 --disable-cgi",
"PHP_CFLAGS=-fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64",
"PHP_CPPFLAGS=-fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64",
"PHP_LDFLAGS=-Wl,-O1 -pie",
"GPG_KEYS=42670A7FE4D0441C8E4632349E4FDC074A4EF02D 5A52880781F755608BF815FC910DEB46F53EA312",
"PHP_VERSION=7.4.23",
"PHP_URL=https://www.php.net/distributions/php-7.4.23.tar.xz",
"PHP_ASC_URL=https://www.php.net/distributions/php-7.4.23.tar.xz.asc",
"PHP_SHA256=cea52313fcffe56343bcd3c66dbb23cd5507dc559cc2e3547cf8f5452e88a05d"
],
"Cmd": [
"/bin/sh",
"-c",
"#(nop) ",
"CMD ["apache2-foreground"]"
],
"Image": "sha256:844b269fc6190d103a5df50166d44a27d448ab6d75364627fc986930c603bec1",
"Volumes": {
"/var/www/html": {}
},
"WorkingDir": "/var/www/html",
"Entrypoint": [
"docker-entrypoint.sh"
],
"OnBuild": null,
"Labels": {},
"StopSignal": "SIGWINCH"
},
"DockerVersion": "20.10.7",
"Author": "",
"Config": {
"Hostname": "",
"Domainname": "",
"User": "",
"AttachStdin": false,
"AttachStdout": false,
"AttachStderr": false,
"ExposedPorts": {
"80/tcp": {}
},
"Tty": false,
"OpenStdin": false,
"StdinOnce": false,
"Env": [
"PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
"PHPIZE_DEPS=autoconf \t\tdpkg-dev \t\tfile \t\tg++ \t\tgcc \t\tlibc-dev \t\tmake \t\tpkg-config \t\tre2c",
"PHP_INI_DIR=/usr/local/etc/php",
"APACHE_CONFDIR=/etc/apache2",
"APACHE_ENVVARS=/etc/apache2/envvars",
"PHP_EXTRA_BUILD_DEPS=apache2-dev",
"PHP_EXTRA_CONFIGURE_ARGS=--with-apxs2 --disable-cgi",
"PHP_CFLAGS=-fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64",
"PHP_CPPFLAGS=-fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64",
"PHP_LDFLAGS=-Wl,-O1 -pie",
"GPG_KEYS=42670A7FE4D0441C8E4632349E4FDC074A4EF02D 5A52880781F755608BF815FC910DEB46F53EA312",
"PHP_VERSION=7.4.23",
"PHP_URL=https://www.php.net/distributions/php-7.4.23.tar.xz",
"PHP_ASC_URL=https://www.php.net/distributions/php-7.4.23.tar.xz.asc",
"PHP_SHA256=cea52313fcffe56343bcd3c66dbb23cd5507dc559cc2e3547cf8f5452e88a05d"
],
"Cmd": [
"apache2-foreground"
],
"Image": "sha256:844b269fc6190d103a5df50166d44a27d448ab6d75364627fc986930c603bec1",
"Volumes": {
"/var/www/html": {}
},
"WorkingDir": "/var/www/html",
"Entrypoint": [
"docker-entrypoint.sh"
],
"OnBuild": null,
"Labels": null,
"StopSignal": "SIGWINCH"
},
"Architecture": "arm",
"Variant": "v7",
"Os": "linux",
"Size": 456959259,
"VirtualSize": 456959259,
"GraphDriver": {
"Data": {
"LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d4ff7707a48034b1c9f4aaa1a6155fdebf079c0b0b952f4793542cfcf4d175f3/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1e41dda2267dd61e58ac2928fc1dae2573007d7d5696c998842e50f93f7def62/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/01b9772262ede28d10ba1abea933072a87b316119fece347e2a5897932b3808a/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8c24afd5ec9c3e2111fde1ef4e9a31ad58f5fa7728aed61d5acf3a846908fc9e/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/17c568b442adb626c1a237b2f1648df49b854108a5f3f84da8ba10e6ab12c31d/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/858e3176a289ef360c843bfe83cd0c1cd31472fb182925376ca3612440d94bf5/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f4aaca0c035e60b5cd5abfa005dda1c41e01d83fe59e6a773e6fe28506de9285/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0fd746eba6b6bff62f623ca29cfa4a9d5998c061403a0dad4e649381de76302a/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/87fdb56380a388f4c5b5608177e68884837558801449a06c5f66aaf03a84b687/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1275f7b4edb2f8cad6a69532f321eb24953be67cdf4944829637f85932bb5f8d/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f19aaa2acbc0a09dfcfccf97a7f813f3edf2b9337e86b4faa5b03fb917c733db/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ecf3e76b43b5c397cd1a6311309958c01144b90028a4aebd75c91e14ea1aa7b1/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5e0168d89a2f8d1ebd8345ac60fa912b532c6c021213fd62faea1d71acbed45c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/2264e04890d6bfcccda33348b936395505aab41f44cf8430d93990c8dfb167e8/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6be8ea2ebd000c5b3619f4d1ccbcd35b72e63b64155a4eecd43bff5332a5d7a3/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c96b4cefe750d9d36871c694607352ef233e1b4fd7ec832aa49d5ceb28f4ada5/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/89d40f63173208285ef462d210ca6b8ab5197b7b15d9b49cf0a53596055238c6/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1cdc0e9e1e32d38382762613f4042180f11ad24ea123ffbe4f47a41890def750/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/69c47578399b1114b64d3f01cf38a944bc934b5994fe945969fb095ef9ffa592/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/2dadd823a8c034bc214777d4c7e6bf0edc829ab522d5b20925b9df5a9aca3abf/diff",
"MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a743da6fd4ce297cd64c24c310b2f5437f357a254f48967aeabe4dfef53dfd5c/merged",
"UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a743da6fd4ce297cd64c24c310b2f5437f357a254f48967aeabe4dfef53dfd5c/diff",
"WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a743da6fd4ce297cd64c24c310b2f5437f357a254f48967aeabe4dfef53dfd5c/work"
},
"Name": "overlay2"
},
"RootFS": {
"Type": "layers",
"Layers": [
"sha256:e8b9a2d8b2469a0315b17bfb011c0be7f6e26a34c5e515e66c5b5ad8b9817e58",
"sha256:7a570569308278a0576df97caca86f54a4c3dbb525b5326a0a06f840fefd1174",
"sha256:f9b1d4487c8dba47f8f595d7a7ddf9608b5463dadf80d72b724aa0bac45d629f",
"sha256:cec7b002a983227b1bc75402511f61549448229db01d4a269df58feb05c8d81d",
"sha256:ea5e12092b68e0632ec7bd85a9003880bc54175ac69f2807a329e39a5fa7ebbe",
"sha256:f578973ab7576d268089c713c58a201117d80e13293e36e1f6345dab72a6ad0f",
"sha256:d1472db3be815f1fff276c8d7d144c8ca8c2f5deecec2d1f7585f5ffbca53028",
"sha256:a57826c457c055d2f24dce9b5cca2319679d84f265e0b6a43db70e1e5156a719",
"sha256:ad358b9f27644cb7b1393422a09fbadbb1e402463e87054a140316767854e888",
"sha256:fb1423855d1d47f101ee16250d48d94a1ba25fbb3db6fb5481a81f83a1ef9572",
"sha256:ff59399357852561704b55eefed20b1283b90b9f878c3d21242e6d6c36268656",
"sha256:99d2ded3e3939ddb44366b47a95a98c49677b739d7f123c6acad2fcfaa89b537",
"sha256:a4950a49256daf317c99328d1fcff9798be7dade43e1206fd8491bc14bd7688c",
"sha256:b0f146d8dd60bd9a44d2e16fbdc8decf5f98bfbe7e53a34f841ce171460c50d2",
"sha256:7a4320646df2d70d507a4d51f1c8eeea191b8bbcb34d0e8d3ea1a6af5a48b89e",
"sha256:4e459e09e1b627d527b9e15e2ccfd6ebc893addaba7a526f135e65506bc31ce7",
"sha256:4ecc521f7def52c91c3be531cfd3ea7fe61ec9bd1e55ef68250f40596acceae0",
"sha256:3d1b8acee747e5488705cb02ceea71b1cff0e47848074f1749ba8b01837b9aa9",
"sha256:31223861334300261fe9bef5decf9ebf08525822ef97c1b559a4df6926aa5f97",
"sha256:e594c5855359d7fe53c877313d841c366b84a29b9192e36daaaa5fa9ce3f23f7",
"sha256:cb2fec1bee70e0c75421c83df6d86c8bb5c3653d037216dfde030ef4f7850ab7"
]
},
"Metadata": {
"LastTagTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
}
}
]
pi@pi3:~ $
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been solved by updating libseccom as in that thread:
https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/issues/635

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).